# How do I close a view after firebase google sign in

Tags: swift, xcode, firebase

I have the code working for a swift 4 firebase google log in.  The problem is after sign in, it just drops me back onto the view that was used for the sign in.  Where do I execute the code to automatically close the view after the sign in?

Comment: It would be more helpful if you could post the code of where you are performing the sign in.

Comment: Please review the following two guides on asking questions: [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Without seeing what you're doing we'd just be guessing as the answer will depend on how your view is being created. In Code? A Segue? IB? Something else?

Answer (score 1):

I am assuming that your code looks something like this.

```
FIRAuth.auth()?.signIn(withEmail: self.emailTextField.text!, password: self.passwordTextField.text!) { (user, error) in

            if error == nil {

                //Print into the console if successfully logged in
                print("You have successfully logged in")

                //Go to the HomeViewController if the login is sucessful
                let vc = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "Home")
                self.present(vc!, animated: true, completion: nil)

                //If you want to go back to the previous view then call
                //For view embedded in navigation controller use,
                self.navigationController?.popViewController(animated: true)

                //For view that was presented use,
                self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)

            } else {

                //Tells the user that there is an error and then gets firebase to tell them the error
                let alertController = UIAlertController(title: "Error", message: error?.localizedDescription, preferredStyle: .alert)

                let defaultAction = UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .cancel, handler: nil)
                alertController.addAction(defaultAction)

                self.present(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)
            }
        }
```